# How can I determine the battery impact of using scaled resolutions on my MB Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, resolution, display, benchmark

*(My machine is a stock mid-2014 MB Pro Retina 13")*

I noticed a definitive drop in how long my battery lasts when I switched to the largest resolution available (to have more space to work with) instead of going with the Default setting.

[image: My current resolution.]

## So my actual question is...

How could I measure battery time in order to test and compare how long it lasts using different resolutions? What kind of tool can I use for that?

I could just start off a normal day's work and notice how long until I'm at 50%, and then try the next day using a different resolution, but I don't think that's too reliable or time-efficient.

Comment: You can use the time as measurement outcome, and real life work as your input. More screen real-estate means more active apps, and more GPU usage, but more work efficiency. But just try it for one week at res x and one week at res y and compare the total time left on your battery. (And the amount of work done)

Comment: But that's not a reliable way to do batter benchmarking, is it? What if this week I have a video to edit, but next week I don't? What if this week I have to do a lot of research and planning, and next week coding and design? I'm looking for a way to benchmark this in a controlled fashion.

Comment: That is going to be hard. I use my computer differently then a benchmark, an especially when I have a higher res. But I understand you need, some automated script that opens and closes and uses different kinds of software. I think these can not be compared with productivity. No, i have no idea for such software. Just run a movie in a loop and see how long it takes before the batt dies.